# Laptop reboots short after starting Windows 10 setup

Tags: installation, windows-installation, windows-10-preview

I am trying to install the Windows 10 insider preview (*Windows10_InsiderPreview_x64_DE-DE_10130*) on following machine.

```
Acer Aspire 5720
Intel Core 2 Duo processor T5250
358MB Intel Graphics X3100
2GB DDR2
160GB HDD
```

I start the installation by booting from an USB device. The installation from this USB drive normally works, because I successfully used it on another machine. The installation only fails on the mentioned Aspire laptop.

I can boot from the USB drive and start the Windows 10 setup application. But approximately 1 minute after Windows 10 logo appeared, the setup aborts and the laptop reboots without showing any message.

There are already some partitions on the HDD. The two recovery partitions, one partition with windows vista, one data partition and 40GB un-partitioned space at the end of the partition table.

Why does the laptop reboot? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setup rebooted the PC, use a Linux Live DVD to get the Windows Logs from `C:\$windows.~bt\Sources` and share them.

If you can't get logs, download the [32Bit version](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=522153). With 2GB of RAM you have no fun with a 64Bit Version. A 64Bit Windows should be only installed if you have 4GB RAM.

Comment: There is no such folder you mentioned on any drive. But the setup of the 32Bit version works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the computer meets the requirements for windows 10 AND 64 bit? If your computer doesn't meet the requirement reboot is mos likely to happen.

Anyway, try to run the windows in safe mode and see what's going on. This will give you a clearer view. If unsuccessful, run the bios at restart and check that all is well after the setup and that the hard drive is properly installed.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I was not able to install windows 10. The setup aborts right after the windows 10 logo (of the setup application) appears. And yes, the laptop fulfills the minimum system requirements (see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq-system-requirements-pc).

Comment: so it might be a problem with the installer itself. did you download it from the Microsoft site?

Comment: The installer works, as I said in my post: "I successfully used it on another machine". And yes, it was downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: So the only problem here is with your machine mate... you do need to run a check on your hardware and make sure all is well.